# Generate a new JSON file from an api with a json response

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, npm, redux

I am working in React Native and I am making an api call which returns a json file. Is it possible then to create a new json file, based on the json received, save it locally and set the state from the local json file? At the moment the function that I am using is the below. Maybe there is a package helping in this task?

```js
export function getData(){
    return (dispatch) => {
        //Make API Call
        fetch("my api url").then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        }).then((data) => {
          var data  = data.articles;
          dispatch({type: DATA_AVAILABLE, data:data});
        })
    };
}
```

Comment: Your keywords are persistence and hydration/rehydration with redux. No idea about writing and reading local files in React Native, but as far as redux goes, you can use `createStore` with `preloadedState`, which would need to be the result of JSON.parse on the file's content. If this needs to happen **while** the app is running (not only once at launch time), you need an action that replaces the entire application state. So something like `FETCH_JSON_SUCCESS` in the root (!) reducer returns `JSON.parse(contentOfFile)`.

Comment: I am new to redux but le me explain the problem better. I can make only 1000 request per day to this api and anyway it is updated only every 15 mins. I was thinking at this point to make the call somewhere out of the app, generate a new json file, and in redux access the json file that I generate. Do you think is possible?

Comment: Yes, the approach would be the same. Either with preloadedState or with an action that just replaces the entire state with the parsed json file.